# Repository Git in a server: Stg, Dev, Live

Tags: git, repository

first of all, i'm newbie on Git. And here is the thing:
We recently migrate to a new server or live site, and we don't have none stage instance.
So i want to have a subdomain to staging (or QA), and another subdomain to development.

I already initialized a `--bare` repository, my question is, ¿how can i add to this repository my site located in the same server?
I'm not adding from my local machine because the site has a 15 GB size. So, it's gonna be so much wasted time.

And after that, I assume that I need to clone the repository into each subdomain, and checkout to stage and development stage respectively, isn't it?

Right now i have this:

```
/var/www/html/live/ (All site files)
/var/www/html/repository.git/
/var/www/html/stging/ (empty)
/var/www/html/dev/ (empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally done through 3 branches within the main bare repo `/var/www/html/repository.git/`.

If that bare repo is empty, you want to make a first commit with the content of your live folder:

```
export GIT_DIR=/var/www/html/repository.git
git config --bool core.bare false
git config user.name yourUserName
git config user.email yourEmail

cd /var/www/html/live
# edit a .gitignore file, listing big files and folders you should ignore
git add .
git commit -m "Live repo import"

# Make two other branches
git branch dev
git branch stg

# restore the bare repo nature
git config --bool core.bare true

unset GIT_DIR
```

Then you can clone your repo in the non-bare instances:

```
cd /var/www/html/live
# no need to checkout HEAD: the files are already there
git clone --no-checkout /var/www/html/repository.git   

cd /var/www/html/stging/ 
git clone --branch stg /var/www/html/repository.git   

cd /var/www/html/dev/
git clone --branch dev /var/www/html/repository.git
```